# Is there a way to access state names from pycountry library?

Tags: python, country-codes

Let's say I want to convert state name to three letter country code using 
`pycountry` library, is there a way to achieve it?

For example (Beroun -> CZE, Faryab -> AFG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the complete address i.e. long/lat/city/countryname using `geopy`:

```
from geopy import geocoders

Google-API-KEY = "xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx"
gn = geocoders.GoogleV3(Google-API-KEY)
place, (lat, lng) = gn.geocode("Beroun")
print(place)
```

OUTPUT:

```
266 01 Beroun, Czechia
```

Once you have the country name, you can then get its abbreviation using `pycountry`:

```
import pycountry
user_input = 'Czechia'
mapping = {country.name: country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries}
print(mapping.get(user_input))
```

OUTPUT:

```
CZ
```

Now you know, for a state, it's country and the abbreviation of it. Create a dictionary out of states and its countries, if you want the key-value paired of `state-country`

perhaps something like:

```
state_country = {'Beroun': 'CZ'}
print(state_country)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'Beroun': 'CZ'}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the following:

```
alpha2 = pycountry.subdivisions.lookup("Beroun").country_code # "CZ"
# If you're looking for alpha_3:
pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=alpha2).alpha_3 # "CZE"
```

However, you have to be careful of ambiguous locations e.g. the US State "Montana"

```
pycountry.subdivisions.lookup("Montana").country_code # BG
```